# why do I need to patch linux kernel to use pandaboard's spi?

Tags: linux-kernel

I believe this question is a bit more general but here is how it goes :

I have read this article about [using pandaboard's SPI](http://www.omappedia.com/wiki/PandaBoard_SPI), especially the part "Configuring and patching the kernel".

It says that you have to edit the driver to use the SPI, by telling the driver what bus you want to use, and I don't really understand why we would need to do so.
If we are compiling the kernel, we specify the `arch` (`omap...`) and so I guess that since the toolchain knows what is the target processor, it knows what are the pin numbers of the SPI (clock, miso, mosi, ...).

So what am I missing here ? Why do we need extra configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPI is meant to be something really hardcoded/for soldered components, as opposed to usb or uart (plug/unplug), that might be a reason why linux "requires" to configure it at compile time.

This is the concept, it is not exactly true : in [this article](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/spi/spi-summary) they say spi drivers can be loaded/unloaded on demand, so no need to burn anything at compile time (but a little bit more complicated to implement)

Answer (score 3):

The extra configuration is telling the kernel what device you've hooked up via SPI and on what pins you connected it.  There's [no standard answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Standards) to that, because there's a wide variety of devices you might connect.

Comment: But why do we need to hardcode this ? it cannot be configured at runtime like for other protocols ? (like speed of tty for instance)